# help: code to record data in csv file from gui MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-io, csv

i'm new to MATLAB. i have this code that extract image feature using gui. i have problem creating a code that can record data extracted into csv and txt file. i want the data extracted from the image to be record into a single csv file each time an image is load into the gui. the data will be use to train a neural network. can some one help me? tq

```
   %~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~use when train data~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   % stt=0; %use it when train data\\set grade value set 1 if pet, set 0 if nonpet
   % humoment=[num2str(M1) ',' num2str(M2) ',' num2str(M3) ',' num2str(M4) ',' num2str(M5) ',' num2str(M6) ',' num2str(M7) ',' num2str(perimeter) ',' num2str(area) ',' num2str(xbar) ',' num2str(ybar) ',' num2str(stt)];
   % Record (humoment,'C:\MATLABDATA\datatrain.csv') %use it when train data
   % %~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~use when test data~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   humoment=[num2str(M1) ',' num2str(M2) ',' num2str(M3) ',' num2str(M4) ',' num2str(M5) ',' num2str(M6) ',' num2str(M7) ',' num2str(perimeter) ',' num2str(area) ',' num2str(xbar) ',' num2str(ybar) ];

    data= [filename ',' num2str(M1) ',' num2str(M2) ',' num2str(M3) ',' num2str(M4) ',' num2str(M5) ',' num2str(perimeter) ',' num2str(M6) ',' num2str(M7) ',' num2str(area) ',' num2str(xbar) ',' num2str(ybar)];
   Record(humoment,'C:\MATLABDATA\datatest.csv')
   Record(data,'C:\MATLABDATA\datatest.txt')  
   set(handles.edit45,'String','Load completed')

   end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution might be to replace

```
   Record(humoment,'C:\MATLABDATA\datatest.csv')
   Record(data,'C:\MATLABDATA\datatest.txt')
```

with

```
fid = fopen('C:\MATLABDATA\datatest.csv','a+');
fprintf(fid,[humoment,'\n']);
fclose(fid);

fid = fopen('C:\MATLABDATA\datatest.txt','a+');
fprintf(fid,[data,'\r\n']);
fclose(fid);
```